# What is this unicode character - u'\xf1'?

Tags: unicode

What is this unicode character  u'\xf1'

Is there a lookup table on the web somewhere? I have seen tables, but nowhere can I search on this character and get the actual representation.

thanks

Comment: What if he doesn't?

Answer (score 10):

It is **ñ** (ntilde).

```
Unicode Hexadecimal: 0x00F1  
Unicode Decimal: 241  
UCS-2 Hexadecimal: 0xF100  
UCS-2 Decimal: 61696  
HTML Hexadecimal: &#x00F1;  
HTML Decimal: &#241;
```

- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f1/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

A search for "unicode character f1" returns what you ask for.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f1/index.htm

See http://www.unicode.org/charts/ for a full 'lookup table' (several hundreds of these actually).

Comment: And yet, years later, googling '\xf1' gets you here

Comment: All hail Stackoverflow.

Comment: "unicode character f1" returns exactly this answer. Note that can change based on time, location, and user.